# Logistic Regression Interaction vs conditioning on one level

Tags: logistic, interaction, sas

I have a data set where the outcome is binary, and is fit as a function of two categorical variables (3-level location and 2-level status) and their interaction. I am interested in two things:

1. whether there is an interaction effect between location and status, and
2. whether the outcome differs across the 3 locations within only one of the statuses.

Here is the first model that I fit in SAS:

```
PROC GENMOD data = comm;
 class loc(ref='10%') status(ref='No');
 model outcome(event='1') = loc status loc*status / d=bin link=logit type3;
 lsmestimate loc*status 'No 70% vs 30%' 0 -1 0 1 0 0/ cl exp;
 lsmestimate loc*status 'No 70% vs 10%' 0 0 0 1 0 -1/ cl exp;
 lsmestimate loc*status 'No 30% vs 10%' 0 1 0 0 0 -1/ cl exp;
RUN;
```

The joint test is not significant, which answers the first question. When I examine the contrasts within the 'No' status, I noticed that only 2 of the 3 are deemed significantly different, while in a raw plot of the data, all three pairwise comparisons look quite different.

```
     Least Squares Means Estimate 
Label          Estimate  SE    Pr > |z| 
No 70% vs 30%  0.63      0.33  0.12 
No 70% vs 10%  1.49      0.40  0.0002
No 30% vs 10%  0.85      0.35  0.02
```

When I fit a model conditioning only on status = 'No', I see that 3 of the 3 are determined to be significant (code and tests below):

```
PROC GENMOD data = comm;
 class loc(ref='10%');
 model outcome(event='1') = loc / d=bin link=logit type3;
 lsmeans loc / cl exp diff;
 where status = 0;
RUN;

     Least Squares Means Estimate 
Label          Estimate  SE    Pr > |z| 
No 70% vs 30%  0.73      0.34  0.03 
No 70% vs 10%  1.64      0.41  <.0001
No 30% vs 10%  0.91      0.36  0.01
```

My question is, can I fit these two separate models and report results from both, or is it more statistically sound to report only comparisons from the full interaction model?